# ¿Cual es la mejor forma de detectar un cambio de contenido en datagridview VS 2008?

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un datagridview, el cual tiene columnas que puedo editar (con la propiedad EditMode : EditOnEnter). Esta grilla la tengo sólo para mostrar datos, porque los valores (sin formateos, para cálculos) los tengo en un arreglo.

Necesito capturar el dato que cambió en la grilla, para también modificar el arreglo. (Y realizar los cálculos dependiende de la celda que cambió). Para esto lo que más se acerca a lo que necesito es el evento CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged. El problema es que también me levanta el evento apenas cambio el primer número de la celda, fuera de eso funciona bien. Pero he intentado varias cosas sin éxito. ¿Alguien que sepa como hacer un workaround para esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el evento CellEndEdit

[DataGridView.CellEndEdit (Evento)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit(v=vs.110).aspx)

con este evento tendras la notificacion cuando la celda se deje de editar.

Por supuesto este se lanzara hay o no realizado un cambio en la celda, pero podrias usarla en conjunto con el CellBeginEdit

[DataGridView.CellBeginEdit (Evento)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellbeginedit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

guardando en una variable el valor original para despues comparalo con el ingresado, si son iguales entonces no se realizo ningun cambio

```
private string temp = "";

public DataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(...)
{
    temp = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
}

public DataGridView1_CellBEndEdit(...)
{
    string cellVaue = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
    if( cellVaue == temp)
    {
        //no se realizo ningun cambio
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias Leandro, resolvió mi problema y de hecho gracias a la validación propuesta, evito tener que hacer cálculos extras.

Answer (score 0):

El evento CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged es precisamente para eso: se produce cada vez que cambia el valor que se está editando, pero en realidad el valor de la celda todavía no se ha establecido.

Para controlar cuando cambia el valor de una celda deberías usar el evento CellValueChanged.